# Can I restore backup when I switch from HDD to SSD on my Laptop

Tags: dual-boot, backup, ssd

So I finally got my 250GB SSD for my Laptop (a Samsung Np530u3c). I have to install Windows and Ubuntu together. I was wondering if I could just restore my Backup I did on my current System to the newly installed one on the SSD? I backed up with the build-in Backups and selected everything but "Trash", "~/Downloads" and "/media".

Do you think this will work?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, this will not work…  The built-in back-up does [a data backup, not a system back-up…](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc)

The easiest way to do what you ask is to:

1. Download the [CloneZilla LiveCD](http://clonezilla.org/downloads/download.php?branch=stable) and burn it.
2. Edit your `fstab` and get rid of all the UIDs and change them back to `/dev/XdY` (where `X` and `Y` are the original drive locations, probably `s` and `a` respectively.
3. Put the SSD in an external enclosure if your computer doesn't allow 2 hard disks to be mounted. (E.g. small laptop)
4. Boot and test your new `fstab`
5. Boot the CloneZilla Live CD
6. [Follow the on-line manual](http://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-live-doc.php) to make a disk-to-disk image from the HDD to the SSD.
7. Shut down
8. Remove the HDD and insert the SSD
9. Boot from the SSD.
10. **Optional:** Edit your `fstab` again to go back to UIDs.

## Done!  :-)